# Proper way to initialize nested structs in C

Tags: c, struct, initialization, memset

When using nested structures I tend to do something like the following. I would like to know if that's the proper way to initialize `structs` in this particular case or if there's a better way of doing it.

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct inner_struct { 
   char *name;
   int account;
} inner;

typedef struct outer_struct {
   int count;
   char *company; 
   inner *my_inner;
} outer;

outer *
initialize_outer (size_t max) {
   outer *out = malloc(sizeof (outer) * max);
   if (out) {
      memset(out, 0, sizeof *out * max);
      out->count = 0;
      out->company = NULL; 
   }   
   return out;
}

inner *
initialize_inner () {
   inner *in = malloc(sizeof (inner));
   if (in) {
      memset(in, 0, sizeof *in);
      in->account = 0;
      in->name = NULL; 
   }   
   return in; 
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
   int i;
   size_t max_out = 20;
   outer *my_out = initialize_outer(max_out);
   for (i = 0; i<max_out;i++) {
      my_out[i].my_inner = initialize_inner();
   }
}
```

Comment: Why do you assign 0 to variables after a memset?

Comment: @Nick: that's exactly the part I wasn't sure of. Apparently is not needed.

Comment: It is not needed: a bigger problem is that you allocate a bunch of `outer`s and then allocate a bunch of `inner`s but assign them just to the first `outer`.

Comment: I meant to do `my_out[i].my_inner`. Thanks for the heads up!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
outer *
initialize_outer (size_t max) {
    outer *out = malloc(sizeof (outer) * max);
    if (out) {
        memset(out, 0, sizeof (outer) * max);
        out->count = 0; // no need assign 0 to 'account' and NULL to 'name' field
        out->company = NULL; // because memset already assigns 0 to it.
    }   
    return out;
}

inner *
initialize_inner (size_t max) {
    inner *in = malloc(sizeof (inner) * max);
    if (in) {
        memset(in, 0, sizeof (inner) * max);
        in->account = 0; // no need assign 0 to 'account' and NULL to 'name' field
        in->name = NULL; // because memset already assigns 0 to it.
    }   
    return in; 
}
```

Try this...I hope this helps...

Comment: so basically `memset` would init the struct fields to `0` regardless their type, is that correct?

Comment: is the above solution(CODE) helpful

Answer (score 4):

Why not use `calloc()`:

```
outer *
initialize_outer (size_t max) {
    return calloc(max, sizeof(outer));
}

inner *
initialize_inner (size_t max) {
    return calloc(max, sizeof(inner));
}
```

---

However, I would probably do this for simplicity:

```
typedef struct outer_struct {
    int count;
    char *company; 
    inner my_inner[];
} outer;

outer *
initialize (size_t max_out, size_t max_in) {
    return calloc(1, (sizeof (outer) + sizeof (inner) * max_in) * max_out);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    size_t max_out = 20, max_in = 10; 
    outer *my_out = initialize(max_out, max_in);
    ...
}
```

Comment: This is a nice approach too. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Apart from the superfluous assignments to zero, you should probably call initialize_inner from initialize_outer, since it doesn't seem like "outer" fills any purpose without "inner.

This brings up another issue: you should consider using proper, object-oriented program design, with private encapsulation.

inner.h

```
typedef struct inner_struct;


inner* inner_init (void);
void   inner_free (inner* in); // you need a cleanup function!

// an example of a "setter" function:
void init_set_name (inner* in, const char* name);  

// similar setter and getter functions needed here
```

inner.c

```
#include "inner.h"

typedef struct { 
   char* name;
   int   account;
} inner;

inner* inner_init (void) 
{
   inner* in = calloc(1, sizeof (inner));
   if (in == NULL)
   {
     // error_handling
   }

   return in; 
}

void inner_free (inner* in)
{
  // if in->name was allocated dynamically, free it here

  free(in);
}

void init_set_name (inner* in, const char* name)
{
  // assign name to in->name, possibly malloc memory for it
}
```

outer.h

```
#include "inner.h"

typedef struct outer_struct;


outer* outer_init (void);
void   outer_free (outer* out);

// setter and getter functions needed here
```

outer.c

```
#include "outer.h"

typedef struct 
{
   int count;
   char *company; 
   inner *my_inner;
} outer;


outer* outer_init (void) 
{
   outer* out = calloc(1, sizeof(outer));
   if(out == NULL)
   {
     // error handling
   }

   out->my_inner = inner_init();

   return out;
}

void outer_free (outer* out)
{
  inner_free(out->my_inner);
  free(out);
}
```

the_application.c

```
#include "outer.h"

#define MAX_OUT 20

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

   outer* out_arr [MAX_OUT]

   for(int i=0; i<MAX_OUT; i++)
   {
     out_arr[i] = outer_init();
   }

   ...

   for(int i=0; i<MAX_OUT; i++)
   {
     outer_free(out_arr[i]);
   }
}
```